# Testing Performance of a Java method

Tags: java, performance, performance-testing

I have a Java program with a method that accepts 2 strings and checks if they are anagrams of one another.

I believe there are more than one ways to determine if 2 strings are anagrams -

logic - 1 : sort strings and check if they are equal
logic - 2 : check frequency of the strings

and there are many other ways.

End of the day, we can have multiple methods [each of them having different logic] taking 2 strings and checking if they are anagrams.

What are different ways to check the performance of these methods and determine the optimistic one?

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Did you implement some possibilities and compare their performance?  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for pointers on how to ask appropriate questions on SO.

Comment: Also, you've asked 70 questions and accepted only 36 answers... did you not receive answers to the other 34?

Comment: @Jim: Thanks for pointing me out to the FAQ :-) I definitely believe this question is related to algorithms so you could even put in that fashion!

Comment: @Jim: I know I haven't closed at least half of my questions because no concrete answer was provided to some of them. But this is long due now. I am in the processing of closing a few ....thanks

Comment: I am really NOT sure [may be someone can help me understand!] how this question was categorized under debate / arguments / extended discussion when only one individual was able to provide a common answer. Java Performance Testing is something that teams work day and night to keep up. In context, I am just asking ways to performance this piece of code!

Answer (score 1):

You can get

- the time complexity by understanding the algorithm used.
- measure the time taken for different length strings once the code has warmed up.

Sorting the String is order O(n * ln(n)) and O(n) space. Using a counter per character is O(n) time and O(m) for space (where m is the range of characters).  I imagine which is faster is unlikely to matter in any real program, but I assume this is an exercise.